# What structure is underlying Java TreeSet?

Tags: java, treeset, red-black-tree

Java `TreeSet` is a red-black tree self balancing structure.

But what is the structure to store the data? Array or linked list?

Comment: It's a red-black tree. It's not an array, it's not a linked list, it's a tree.

Comment: You just answered your own question. It's a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Comment: have you guys ever heard how trees are stored at memory? I mean linked nodes or nodes at array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeSet` is backed by a `TreeMap` (in similar way `HashSet` is backed by `HashMap`). If you look at `TreeSet` constructor:

```
public TreeSet() {
    this(new TreeMap<E,Object>());
}
```

`TreeMap` internally stores data using nodes represented with `TreeMap.Entry` class:

```
static final class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> left;
    Entry<K,V> right;
    Entry<K,V> parent;
    boolean color = BLACK;
...
```

There is no additional array or list there.

Comment: So nodes are linked to each other by references